# Allow hot network questions to be dismissed?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

I would like to request an option to be able to dismiss a specific hot network question. I am thinking of something like being able to click on an x near the question that would prevent it from appearing again.

Just as an example:

[image: example]

While that Ukrainian Language question might be a good question. I have no idea what it is asking (even after clicking on it). An example that I would like to dismiss.

Comment: Why exactly? They're not exactly intrusive, so why dismiss them?

Comment: @Bart because I like to hop around and view some of the hot network questions that catch my eye. Think of it like a news feed of the site after you are done being able to dismiss it and get a new question for that slot.

Comment: So in addition you would like it to act as a set of slots to be filled with new content, as soon as you dismiss content you're no longer interested in?

Comment: @Bart I could see that being useful as well but just mainly I would just love an option of I've already seen this question enough times/does not interest me so I don't see it over and over again

Comment: Now if they could just make it possible to scratch a HNQ from the list by the actual site community itself for everybody across the network, we'd be solving the core problem behind HNQ.

Comment: The Ukranian ones shouldn't actually be showing up. There's supposed to be a filter that excludes non-English questions from appearing in the HNQ but it has to be turned on manually.

Answer (score 4):

#### I would like to request an option to be able to dismiss a specific hot network question

You can use the [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) user script to do this.

One of its many useful options is to filter the Hot Network Questions list in several different ways:

- block by word
- block by site
- block by title (regexp)

[image]

In your case you would enable "block by site".